# Stacked bar going right to left instead of left to right

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create a simple single stacked bar chart that goes left to right.

I've adapted the code [found here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3943967), and I've gotten pretty close.
However, the stacked data is in the wrong direction.

The data at index 0 is all the right to the right, and the data at index 2 is all the way to the left.

I have a feeling it's got something to do with the rectangle and transition, but I'm not sure where I went wrong.

```
var rect = layer.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.y);
  })
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
  .attr("width", 0);

rect.transition()
  .delay(function(d, i) {
    return i * 10;
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.x0 + d.x);
  })
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return x(d.x0) - x(d.x0 + d.x);
  });
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Javalsu/zkbxeby8/10/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason your stack starts at the right is that the range of your scale [width, 0] is inversely correlated to your domain [0, xStackMax]. Smaller input values will thus lead to larger output values, so your first x/x0 values will end up with values at the 'width' end of the scale.

Fix this so they both go in the same direction.

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, xStackMax])
  .range([0, width]);
```

Then change the x and width .attr calcs, the rects start at their scaled x0 coord and are as wide as the difference between x(d.x0 + d.x) - x(d.x0). For linear scales this can be simplified to x(d.x)

```
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.x0);
  })
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return x(d.x0 + d.x) - x(d.x0);
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zkbxeby8/14/